# Atomicity multiple MySQL subqueries in an INSERT/UPDATE query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am planning on writing the following query:

```
INSERT INTO summary (user_id, total_points, count_operations)
SELECT 
   15 AS user_id,
   (SELECT SUM(points) FROM operations WHERE user_id = 15) AS total_points,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM operations WHERE user_id = 15) AS count_operations
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
total_points = VALUES(total_points), 
count_operations = VALUES(count_operations);
```

Is the whole statement atomic? i.e. does MySQL (with MyISAM engine) internally locks the `operations` table?

Is there a possibility that MySQL would execute the two subsqueries sequentially which could result in some cases (if a new operation is added within that timeframe) that the `total_points` and `count_operations` would be inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM still uses [table-level locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html).

> These storage engines avoid deadlocks by always requesting all needed
>   locks at once at the beginning of a query and always locking the
>   tables in the same order. The tradeoff is that this strategy reduces
>   concurrency; other sessions that want to modify the table must wait
>   until the current DML statement finishes.

So other processes that want to update the tables you're using have to wait until your transaction is finished. If it puts a read lock on the table "operations", all subsequent write locks go into a queue and wait.

Comment: Ok so if I understand your answer correctly, MySQL will very probably lock the operations table so I should not worry about inconsistent results. A downside is that the whole table is locked for the duration of the operation which possibly reduces the concurrency (as opposed to using row-level locking with InnoDB).

Comment: Yes. If locking is a problem, think about switching to the INNODB engine. It does row-level locking.